# How to retrieve the referer in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set HTTP_REFERER when testing in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542856/how-do-i-set-http-referer-when-testing-in-rails)

I tried `request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]` but it returned nil.

I need to track where the user comes from (external sites)

Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try:

```
request.referer
```

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I miss speled words. It works!