# Rails - Functional testing of redirect_to(request.referer)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, functional-testing

Maybe I just missing the forest for the trees again, but I can't seem to figure out a way to write a functional test that tests a :destroy action that redirects to request.referer.

Code is:

```
  def destroy
    @step = Step.find(params[:id])
    @step.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(request.referer) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end
```

Failing test is:

```
  test "should destroy step" do
    assert_difference('Step.count', -1) do
      delete :destroy, :id => @step.to_param
    end
    assert_redirected_to request.referer
  end
```

Having no luck using:

```
redirect_to(:back)
```

... as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it.

Passing test is:

```
  test "should destroy step" do
    assert_difference('Step.count', -1) do
      @request.env['HTTP_REFERER'] = 'http://test.com/steps/1'
      delete :destroy, :id => @step.to_param
    end
    assert_redirected_to @request.env['HTTP_REFERER']
  end
```

Thanks to help from: [How do I set HTTP_REFERER when testing in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542856/how-do-i-set-http-referer-when-testing-in-rails)

Comment: a mere comment: some browsers don't send any referer so you'd better have an additional solution

Comment: Oh.  That's good to know.  Thanks.  I think the answer here is to layout my app differently to streamline navigation.

Answer (score 0):

you write an integration test and use one of delete_via_redirect which should follow the redirect. You may also have to set the the HTTP_REFERER header - see guide.rubyonrails.org