# Testing a redirect_to(:back) on successful from completion isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I'm trying to run a test that has a `redirect_to(:back)` on a successful  form completion, I get this error when I run this line

```
assert_difference 'Comment.count', 1 do
      post comments_path, comment: { body:  "OPTC", commentable_id: 1, commentable_type: 'Post'}
end
```

error
`ActionController::RedirectBackError: No HTTP_REFERER was set in the request to this action, so redirect_to :back could not be called successfully. If this is a test, make sure to specify request.env["HTTP_REFERER"].`

[Looking into this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542856/how-do-i-set-http-referer-when-testing-in-rails) I see I need something like  `request.env['HTTP_REFERER'] = 'http://test.com/'` added to the setup. But this just gives the error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'env' for nil:NilClass`

Now I'm not sure what to do. How can I get the first error to go away?

**update**

Im using rails 4

here is the header of the test file

require 'test_helper'

```
class CategoryItemShowPageTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

 def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
    @user1 = users(:archer)
    @guide = Guide.find(1)
    @category = Category.find(1)
    @category_item = CategoryItem.find(1)
    @mod_relationship = game_mods_relationships(:mod1)
    request.env['HTTP_REFERER'] = 'http://test.com/'

  end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set HTTP\_REFERER when testing in Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542856/how-do-i-set-http-referer-when-testing-in-rails)

Comment: @BoraMa I read this question and tried the answer given and it gave me the second error I posed in my question

Comment: Have you tried the solution variants from other answers from the above-linked question? Notably setting the `@request.env` (instead of `request.env`) or passing `HTTP_REFERER` as the second param to `post` as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7275895/1544012)?

Comment: Yes I have tried both. using @request as an instance variable still gives the no method error and passing `HTTP_REFERER` does nothing.

Comment: OK, what rails version do you use then? And can you post the header of the test file so that we can see precisely which parent class is your test class derived from?

Comment: In that case, I am quite sure the third variant should work, something like this: `post comments_path({comment: { body: "OPTC", commentable_id: 1, commentable_type: 'Post' }}, { 'HTTP_REFERER' => 'http://www.somewhere.net' })`. Note the two separate hashes needed for this. See the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb#L37) for documentation.

Comment: @BoraMa ` ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: comment` close to working

Comment: Aha, I made a small mistake, the params should ho to the `post` method, not the path helper. Sorry, my answer should be the final one, I believe :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments above, I believe, this should work OK for setting params and a HTTP referer in a Rails 4 integration test:

```
post comments_path, 
     { comment: { body: "OPTC", commentable_id: 1, commentable_type: 'Post' } }, 
     { 'HTTP_REFERER' => 'http://www.somewhere.net' }
```