# Test failure - after redirect_to request.referrer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing

A User can submit a form to create a Scheduling from more than one place and should subsequently be returned to the original place of form submission.

My Schedulings Controller, therefore relies on `request.referrer`. It works as intended in development and looks something like this:

```
class SchedulingsController < ApplicationController
#stuff not relevant to the question removed
  def create
    @scheduling = current_user.schedulings.build(scheduling_params)
     if @scheduling.save
       redirect_to request.referrer
       flash[:success] = "scheduled!"
     else
     # do something not relevant to the question
     end
   end
end
```

I wish to run a Rails integration test to test this. `request.referrer` however appears to always be nil in the Test environment, so with help from an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542856/how-do-i-set-http-referer-when-testing-in-rails) I have worked around this by including a headers hash in the Post request like this:

```
class SchedulingsCreateTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
 
  test "valid input for new scheduling" do
    assert_difference 'Scheduling.count', 1 do
      post schedulings_path, params: { scheduling: { start_time: Time.now },
                                       headers: { "HTTP_REFERER" => "http://example.com/workouts" }
    end

    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'workouts/index'
    assert_not flash.empty?
  end
```

This test fails at `assert_not flash.empty?`
What is happening, why is the flash assessed as empty?

I note that if, in the controller, I change `redirect_to request.referrer` to `redirect_to workouts_path` (or `workouts_url`), the test passes.

Thanks for your interest and any help.

Daniel

Comment: Although I broadly resolved this (see solution below),  it does still beg the question why 
assert_template 'workouts/index' passed originally with the errant HTTP_REFERER value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have broadly solved my own question by changing the value in the headers hash from:

`"http://example.com/workouts"` to `"http://www.example.com/workouts"`

the former is shown in an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542856/how-do-i-set-http-referer-when-testing-in-rails) and is sourced directly from the Rails Guide, however working in Rails 5, I found the “www” is necessary.

I got to the bottom of this with an extra line in my test:

`assert_redirected_to workouts_url` before `the follow_redirect!`, which failed and identified the url discrepancy.

Daniel